# Is this collection of subsets of counting numbers a sigma algebra?

Tags: real-analysis, probability-theory

Let $S = \Bbb N$ the set of counting numbers and $\mathcal B =  $ {A $\subseteq S :$ A is finite or $A^c$ is finite}. Is $\mathcal B$ a sigma algebra?

I need to prove this or give a counterexample.

As far as I can tell, it satisfies the definition of a sigma algebra. The null set is in $\mathcal B$. I think it is closed under complementation, since any subset A in $\mathcal B$ will obviously result in $A^c$ being in $\mathcal B$. And since we are working with counting numbers here, it should be closed under countable unions. Therefore, I think that $\mathcal B$ IS a sigma algebra.

Is my logic ok here, or did I miss something?

Comment: Could you go into a little more detail on why it's closed under countable unions?

Comment: Is $\{1\}\cup\{3\}\cup\{5\}\cup\{7\}\cup\cdots\in\mathcal B$?

Comment: Sure. My thought was that given any $A_1, A_2, ... , A_n \in  \mathcal B$, each of them is a subset containing natural numbers, therefore a union of them would still contain natural numbers and therefore still be contained in $\mathcal B$

Comment: Oh man...the odd numbers, I didn't even think of that! So that would be a union of subsets of $\mathcal B$, but neither that union nor its complement is in $\mathcal B$. Therefore, it's not a sigma algebra!

Comment: "Therefore"? Maybe I didn't understand the definition of $\mathcal B$. Is $\mathcal B$ the collection of **all** sets of natural numbers? So, if a set contains nothing but natural numbers, then we know it belongs to $\mathcal B$? OK, you're right, the collection of **all** sets of natural numbers **is** a $\sigma$-algebra.

Comment: No, $\mathcal B$ is the collection of sets of natural numbers where either the set or its complement is finite. That's why I think that the even/odd number sets break it.

Comment: Every finite set of natural numbers belongs to $\mathcal B.$ Every set of naturall numbers is a countable union of finite sets. If $\mathcal B$ were closed under countable unions, then every set of natural numbers would belong to $\mathcal B.$

Comment: I see. But since the set of even numbers does not belong to $\mathcal B$, then $\mathcal B$ is not closed under countable unions and is not a sigma algebra.